# Updating a Score keeper

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, game-center

I am having a lot of difficulty at the moment with updating the score on the GUI of my basic game in python.

I currently have the code such that it appears in the top left hand corner, with the score appearing as "O". However, the score remains at `0` for the entirety of the program (as it is only getting rendered once. I am unsure how to constantly rerender the score to update it? I have tried many methods and have been unsuccessful. The part of the code with the score render and my attempt at keeping track of the score using the variable `conlisionNumber` is:

```
new = bears[:]
    for bear in new: #this makes a copy of the array
        if player.colliderect(bear):
            windowSurface.blit(bearImageTwo, bear)
            windowSurface.blit(playerImageTwo, player)

        def explosion():
            for bear in bears:
                if player.colliderect(bear) and (moveLeft == False and moveRight == False and moveUp == False and moveDown == False):
                    bears.remove(bear)
                    colisionNumber += 1

        if player.colliderect(bear) and (moveLeft == False and moveRight == False and moveUp == False and moveDown == False):
                t = Timer(1, explosion)
                t.start()

    scoreFont = pygame.font.SysFont("impact", 20)
    score = scoreFont.render("SCORE:" + str(colisionNumber), True, (192,192,192))
    windowSurface.blit(score, (10,10))
```

Please note: at the start of the program I put:

```
global colisionNumber
colisionNumber = 0
```

This was done because if I defined `colisionNumber` within explosion, then `colisionNumber` would not be defined in the `score` variable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You answered your own question. colisionNumber is global but inside the function explosion you try to set it and it makes a local copy. You need to define it as global in the function. (Its a keyword) The global keyword goes in the function not on the original definition - by virtue of being outside of any function or class it is global.

Comment: Use `colisionNumber = 0` at the beginning of your program and `global colisionNumber` in function which change `colisionNumber` value.

Answer (score 1):

```
colisionNumber = 0

def explosion():
    global colisionNumber
    colisionNumber += 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone! Super happy it finally worked.